Disable CMD/PS/etc. for a single user *without* using Active Directory GPO
I have a server running Server 2022 that has two local users, one admin and one standard.
I need to disable several features (cmd, powershell, ctrl alt del, edge, etc) for the standard user while allowing the admin user access to them without using Active Directory GPO. This machine is specifically and intentionally NOT on a domain, so I cannot use AD GPO.
I've already used the local GPO editor, but it disables the features for both users. I need to allow the admin user access to these features while preventing the standard user from accessing them.
What is the best way to proceed?

Yes, the Local group policy applies to all users, so it's not a good choice for this. A simple way to block running certain tools is remove the "Read & Execute" file permissions for the local Users group or explicitly deny access for that one user - on the cmd.exe or msedge.exe files themselves. Alternatively, AppLocker policies can be used to block apps instead, but it's much more complicated to set up initially

Local Group Policy can be applied to specific users.

Open mmc.exe as your local admin account.
File > Add/Remove Snap-In. Double-click Group Policy Object Editor.
In the Select Group Policy Object dialog, under Group Policy Object, click Browse.
Open the Users tab and select the user or group the policies should apply to.

Once you've finished this process the USER policies you choose and apply will apply to the user (or group) you have selected. Setting Computer policies may still apply system-wide, but User policies should be limited to the selected user scope.
